# Trouble getting TigerVNC working with current X11 session

Tags: fedora, x11, nvidia, vnc, x11vnc

I have a remote PC with a RTX600 GPU and nVidia drivers on Fedora 36 with two physical monitors attached.  I'm trying to remote into the current X11 session but getting strange behavior.

I'm using TigerVNC and specifically the x0vncserver command.  If I start a server like this:

```
x0vncserver -display :1 -localhost=0 -PasswordFile $HOME/.vnc/passwd
```

this is the immediate output:

```
Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 7680x2160+0+0
XDesktop:    Using evdev codemap
XDesktop:    
XDesktop:    XTest extension present - version 2.2
Main:        Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5900
```

I can successfully connect to it from another computer, but when I do, the physical screens connected to the server PC will flash back then a lower resolution version of the current X11 session is displayed on display 2.  This lower res desktop is also displayed over VNC on the client PC.  This is the VNC server output:

```
Connections: accepted: 172.23.86.235::60395
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Thu Mar 30 17:54:11 2023
 XDesktop:    Enabling 8 buttons of X pointer device
 XDesktop:    Allocated shared memory image

Thu Mar 30 17:54:12 2023
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
 Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 7680x2160+0+0
 Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 7680x2160+0+0
 Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 1280x800+0+0
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 66.3552 Mpixels in / 1.44073 Mpixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:46.0567 ratio)
 Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 1280x800+0+0
```

Also if i try and set the -geometry parameter,  x0vncserver crashes when the client connects:

```
x0vncserver -display :1 -geometry 1920x1080+0+0 -localhost=0 -PasswordFile $HOME/.vnc/passwd

Thu Mar 30 17:57:15 2023
 Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 1920x1080+0+0
 XDesktop:    Using evdev codemap
 XDesktop:    
 XDesktop:    XTest extension present - version 2.2
 Main:        Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5900

Thu Mar 30 17:57:27 2023
 Connections: accepted: 172.23.86.235::51010
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Thu Mar 30 17:57:33 2023
 XDesktop:    Enabling 8 buttons of X pointer device
 XDesktop:    Allocated shared memory image
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888

Thu Mar 30 17:57:34 2023
 Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 1920x1080+0+0
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 (X_ShmGetImage)
```

Is there something I'm missing?  How do I correctly setup a VNC server to display the current X11 session with nVidia drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

There is things you can try:

1. You can disable hardware acceleration, go to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add those lines under `Device`

   Option "UseSHM" "false"

   Option "UseDamage" "false"

then restart.

2. Use a desired screen resolution, for that you first need to run `xrandr` to see the available resolution then pick one like this `xrandr --output <output-name> --mode <desired-resolution>`
3. Try to start VNC server with the correct display, maybe you are using the wrong one, pick the :0 one with this `x0vncserver -display :0 -localhost=0 -PasswordFile $HOME/.vnc/passwd`
4. If nothing work you can try another VNC client like TurboVNC which is designed for nVidia